# Compiling Scala^Z3 on Windows

Tags: scala, z3

I tried to compile Scala^Z3 on Win XP using Cygwin and JDK 1.7.0 but it didn't work out as expected.

I did the following:
- Use SBT 0.7.4
- Use current Scala^Z3 revision from github
- Use Cygwin and its gcc
- Use JDK 1.7.0 (javac)

"sbt update" was successfull.
"sbt package" end up in several errors stating undefined references like the following:

> > \psuter-ScalaZ3-35cb691\src\c/z3_Z3Wrapper.c:10: undefined reference to `_Z3_mk_config'

In order to make it work at all I changed ....\PSuterScalaZ3\psuter-ScalaZ3-35cb691\project\build\scalaz3.scala line 74 to:

> > lazy val gcc : ManagedTask = if(isUnix || is32bit) {

On the homepage it is stated that it should work for Windows, too. Does it at all?
Is there a precompiled jar available?

I saw a z3.jar here: http://lara.epfl.ch/~psuter/jniz3/z3.jar
This is a Linux Version too, I guess? Because it didn't work for me either...

Scala^Z3 is a really good piece of code (if i can get it to work ;))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that, the sbt script indeed currently only works for Linux (and as you can tell by the absolute path, we're not quite used to having external users yet).

Here are the steps I use to compile it under Windows:

- compile all Java sources with javac (there are no dependencies)
- generate the header files using javah
- compile all the Scala sources with scalac (using only the Java .class files as dependencies)
- compile the .c + .h files with Visual Studio
- manually create a jar file with everything

We also hope to release a precompiled .jar file with the shared library for Linux and Windows once we adapted Scala^Z3 to the new changes in Z3 3.1.

**EDIT** The GitHub repository now contains a precompiled .jar file prepared for Scala 2.9.1 and Z3 3.2. It works under Windows and Linux (32bit). The repository also contains more detailed instructions on how to compile the shared library in Windows, using MinGW instead of Visual Studio (hence removing the need for VS runtime libraries).

Comment: A precompiled .jar (Z3 3.1) would be awesome... when do you think this could be available? Its because we need the .parseSmtlib2String() method.

Comment: I used the precompiled .jar (Version 1.1 with z3.dll 2.19) but it states: "WARNING: Out of allocated virtual memory. Unable to allocate object of size 1561721928. Current allocation size: 142676. High watermark: 0" when defining just a the little term from the ppt slides on Scala^Z3 Homepage. What could be wrong? Does it really need that much RAM? Wrong DLL?

Comment: Hopefully by the end of next week. The memory problem could come from the fact that the latest Z3 has two ways of managing the memory; manually or automatically. I'm not sure how using the shared library compiled against an older Z3 interacts with that aspect.

Comment: Looking forward to it ;) Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: I have added a precompiled version to GitHub. (Including support for parseSMTLIB2String and parseSMTLIB2File.) I have tested it myself under Windows and Linux (32bit). You can get it either from the repository itself (in jar-releases/32/scala-2.9.1/scalaz3-3.2.a.jar), or from GitHub as a "package download". Hote this helps. I will also try to automate the process so that it is accessible from sbt in Windows. Currently it is not.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem some months back and here is what it I had to do in order to compile it with Visual Studio 2010. I am not sure if it is still relevant since Scala^Z3 and Z3 itself changed a lot, but I hope it nevertheless is helpful.

1. Created a new Visual C++ Win32 project (.NET Framework 4) for
   creating DLLs.
2. Added all .h and .c files in the src/c/ directory. VC somehow
   complained about the "inline" modifier and a work mate suggested to
   remove them, which I did.
3. Added z3.h from Z3 2.19, Z3 2.16 wasn't accepted. Also added the
   corresponding z3.lib (x86, haven't tried x64 yet). VC wouldn't accept
   z3.dll and complaint about the file being corrupt. No clue why, Z3
   itself works fine for me.
4. The project compiles with 13 warnings and a dll is created which
   apparently MUST be named scalaz3.dll.
5. sbt compile, adding scalaz3.dll to lib-bin, jar the whole thing
   together to scalaz3.jar
6. 'scala -classpath scalaz3.jar test.scala' with scalaz3.jar and z3.dll
   in the current folder works

Comment: Thanks for these detailed steps. The .dll indeed must be called scalaz3.dll. When you run Scala^Z3, it asks the system to try and load a library with that exact name. If that fails, it looks for a file of that name in the .jar, copies it to a temporary directory and loads it from there. (The temporary directory name contains a hash of the current version of Scala^Z3 to avoid conflicts.) The name also must be libscalaz3.so on *nix systems, and would probably be libscalaz3.jnilib on MacOSX, were Z3 supported on that platform.

Comment: I finally found out how to compile the shared library using MinGW only, so now there are no dependencies outside of z3.dll anymore.